# Check uploaded file consist 2 decimal places or pormpt error message

Tags: struts2

I would like your help. I need to check when a file uploaded the decimal format is 2 decimal places. If it is more than 2 decimal places an error message must be prompted. Is there  any way i can do it using struts.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I not sure where to start.. as validation need take from object. kinda of confused.